# sass-loader can't resolve @use rule

Tags: vue.js, sass, sass-loader

I'm working on a vuejs app and I'm trying to import my variables files using the `@use` rule within `prependData` in `sass-loader`, but it seems not working properly. Using `@use` import does not work and I receive erros about variables. But using `@import` everything goes fine. Am I doing something wrong or getting the wrong concept about `@use` rule?

Using `@import` in `prependData` works:

```js
css: {
  loaderOptions: {
    sass: {
      implementation: require('sass'),
      sassOptions: {
        indentedSyntax: true
      },
      // prependData: `@use '~abstracts/variables'` //this does not work
      prependData: `@import '~abstracts/variables'` //this works
    }
  }
}
```

Using `@use` does not work:

```sh
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
15 │     color: $chuck
   │            ^^^^^^
   ╵
```

My package.json:

```
"sass": "^1.26.3",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
```

My component:

```html
<style lang="sass">
    .title
        color: $chuck
</style>
```

My variables.sass file:

```
$chuck: #BADA55
```

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out what I was missing.

Just add `as *`:

```js
css: {
  loaderOptions: {
    sass: {
      implementation: require('sass'),
      sassOptions: {
        indentedSyntax: true
      },
      prependData: `@use '~abstracts/variables' as *`
    }
  }
}

I'm just getting used to this new way of using sass.
```

Comment: ⚠️ `prependData` has changed to `additionalData` in `v9` ([see changelog](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#900-2020-07-02))